# TypeError: Google Apps script cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

I am new to google appscript when I run the code below I  get

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'namedValues' of undefined
> moveEventToBookedCalendar @ Code.gs:7

As you can see above it has a trigger.

```
const FREE_SLOTS_CALENDAR_ID = "\*\*\*@group.calendar.google.com"

const BOOKED_SLOTS_CALENDAR_ID = "\*\*\*\*@group.calendar.google.com"


function moveEventToBookedCalendar(e) {
  var startingTime = new Date(e.namedValues['DateOne'])
  const availableCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(FREE_SLOTS_CALENDAR_ID)
  const bookedCalendar = CalendarApp.getCalendarById(BOOKED_SLOTS_CALENDAR_ID)
  var endingTime = new Date(startingTime.getTime() + 1000 * 60 * 600)
  var events = availableCalendar.getEvents(startingTime, endingTime)
  events.forEach(event => {
    event.deleteEvent()
    bookedCalendar.createEvent("Booked slot",startingTime, endingTime)

  })

}
```

basicallly the function should connect to my calendars based on someone's response on google forms it should move a selected date from free to booked date.

Comment: How is `moveEventToBookedCalendar` being executed, via some sort of trigger?  How is event object `e` being defined?  From your error message, it looks like its `undefined`.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Presumably you are using a onFormSubmit trigger for a Spreadsheet and not a form so then try this:

`var startingTime = new Date(e.namedValues['DateOne'][0])`